# Can a Wizard use Magic Missile against an Enemy she cannot see?

Tags: dnd-4e, line-of-sight

If an **Enemy** is shrouded in total darkness that blocks line-of-sight, but the **Enemy** is not **Hidden**, can the Wizard attack that Enemy with **Magic Missile**?

From the [**Errata on Magic Missile**](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf)[PDF]:

> **Ranged 20**
>   **Target:** One creature
>   **Effect:** 2 + Intelligence modifier force damage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**,

You do not need Line of Sight unless the spell specifies it (Rules Compendium pg. 106).  **Magic Missile** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=463)</sup> does not have this restriction.

The wizard must have **Line of Effect** to the target creature though.